# SQL Foreign keys count

Tags: sql, count, jpql

Table `Person` has columns `id` and `parent_id`.

I need get a table with columns `id` and `children_count`. How can it be performed? Why I can not write something like this? :

```
SELECT 
    id, count(parent_id) AS children_count
FROM 
    Person
GROUP BY 
    parent_id;
```

Comment: looks like the SQL should work. What specific error are you getting?

Comment: If you want the count of parent_ids per id, you need to group by id not parent_id

Comment: it is not working, because in GROUP BY clause can be only columns from SELECT clause

Comment: Grouping by id has no right effect, because it creates groups of one row, and count will be 1 for row with not NULL parant_id or 0 with NULL.

Comment: Did you have a look here - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic730136-149-1.aspx#bm730141 at the final post on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should outer join the table to itself to find all ids and its children and then calculate the count.

```
select a.id parent,
       count(b.id) count_child
  from person a left outer join person b
    on a.id = b.parent_id
 group by a.id
 order by a.id;
```

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4505/2).

Same result can be achieved using right outer join also.

```
select b.id parent,
       count(a.id) count_child
  from person a right outer join person b
    on a.parent_id = b.id
 group by b.id
 order by b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i mean. But now i have issue how this sql query rewrite to JPQL, where i can not define ON... :(( JPQL makes join on a.parent_id=b.id

Comment: I'm not aware of JPQL. But, check the third query in [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4505/13).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the Select portion of your query is the problem. The below will give you the count of children for each parent_id

```
SELECT parent_id, count(id) AS children_count 
FROM Person 
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Comment: Yes, but it dont returns results for all id's:( I need it for each id not just parent_id

Comment: is there another table containing the Parent items or is this a self-referencing table?

Comment: This is self-referencing table. For those ID witch has no parent_id (it means the value is null), i want to have in result table children_count = 0